# Why does the == operator work for Nullable<T> when == is not defined?

Tags: c#, operators, operator-overloading, nullable

I was just looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602820/129164), which contains the code for `Nullable<T>` from .NET Reflector, and I noticed two things:

1. An explicit conversion is required when going from `Nullable<T>` to `T`.
2. The `==` operator is not defined.

Given these two facts, it surprises me that this compiles:

```
int? value = 10;
Assert.IsTrue(value == 10);
```

With the code `value == 10`, either `value` is being magically converted to an `int` (hence allowing `int`'s `==` operator to be used, or the `==` operator is being magically defined for `Nullable<int>`. (Or, I presume less likely, Reflector is leaving out some of the code.)

I would expect to have to do one of the following:

```
Assert.IsTrue((value.Equals(10)); // works because Equals *is* defined
Assert.IsTrue(value.Value == 10); // works because == is defined for int
Assert.IsTrue((int?)value == 10); // works because of the explicit conversion
```

These of course work, but `==` also works, and that's the part I don't get.

The reason I noticed this and am asking this question is that I'm trying to write a struct that works somewhat similarly to `Nullable<T>`. I began with the Reflector code linked above, and just made some very minor modifications. Unfortunately, my `CustomNullable<T>` doesn't work the same way. I am not able to do `Assert.IsTrue(value == 10)`. I get "Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `CustomNullable<int>` and `int`".

Now, no matter how minor the modification, I would not expect to be able to do...

```
CustomNullable<T> value = null;
```

...because I understand that there is some compiler magic behind `Nullable<T>` that allows values to be set to `null` even though `Nullable<T>` is a struct, but I *would* expect I should be able to mimic all the other behaviors of `Nullable<T>` if my code is written (almost) identically.

Can anyone shed light on how the various operators of `Nullable<T>` work when they appear not to be defined?

Comment: Perhaps the Nullable class is override the == operator. Perhaps that is what is going on?

Comment: Good question. Now ask yourself this question: why can you add an int and a nullable int and get a nullable int?  The Nullable<T> class does not define an addition operator.

Comment: @Eric, I was going to experiment with the other operators, but I figured that I'd start by posting my findings about `==`. In any case, it seems to be that `Nullable<T>` is a "privileged" struct that the compiler treats differently than any struct I would write myself. I already knew about the magic that allows you to set a nullable to `null`, but I guess there is yet more magic. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @DanM: Nullable is *nothing but magic*. See my answer for details. My recommendation for you is to thoroughly acquaint yourself with all the rules for operator overloading and nullable lifting before you attempt to emulate them; the specification makes fascinating reading.

Comment: Shouldn't the third line of the expecting working code be `Assert.IsTrue((int)value == 10);` instead of `Assert.IsTrue((int?)value == 10);`? Using `(int?)` is the surprise, as stated beforehand, not an expectation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Given these two facts, it surprises me that this compiles

Given only those two facts, that is surprising.

Here's a third fact: **in C#, most operators are 'lifted to nullable'**.

By "lifted to nullable", I mean that if you say:

```
int? x = 1;
int? y = 2;
int? z = x + y;
```

then you get the semantics of "if either x or y is null then z is null. If both are not null then add their values, convert to nullable, and assign the result to z."

The same goes for equality, though equality is a bit weird because in C#, equality is still only two-valued. To be properly lifted, equality ought to be three-valued:  x == y should be *null* if either x or y is null, and true or false if x and y are both non-null. That's how it works in VB, but not in C#.

> I would expect I should be able to mimic all the other behaviors of `Nullable<T>` if my code is written (almost) identically.

You are going to have to learn to live with disappointment because your expectation is completely out of line with reality. **`Nullable<T>` is a very special type** and its magical properties are embedded deeply within the C# language and the runtime. For example:

- C# automatically lifts operators to nullable. There's no way to say "automatically lift operators to MyNullable". You can get pretty close by writing your own user-defined operators though.
- C# has special rules for null literals -- you can assign them to nullable variables, and compare them to nullable values, and the compiler generates special code for them.
- The boxing semantics of nullables are deeply weird and baked into the runtime. There is no way to emulate them.
- Nullable semantics for the `is`, `as` and coalescing operators are baked in to the language.
- Nullables do not satisfy the `struct` constraint. There is no way to emulate that.
- And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It's great to have an insider answering our questions. I figured I was going to need to write my own operator overloads, but it's helpful to understand why I'm not getting (nearly) equivalent results from (nearly) equivalent code.

Comment: Could an assignment to a Nullable<ulong> be accidentally atomic depending on the C#/.NET versions and target architecture? I wrote a little WPF program in C# 5.0, Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.2, targeting x64, to try to demonstrate tearing on regular ulong and Nullable<ulong>. I had no problem getting tearing with the regular ulong in a very short amount of time, but so far I have had no luck getting tearing with a Nullable<ulong>. Is it possible that the CLR is magically making the assignment atomic?

Comment: @Eric When you said "C# automatically lifts operators to nullable. There's no way to say "automatically lift operators to MyNullable". You can get pretty close by writing your own user-defined operators though.", would you consider it to be a good or bad practice to define operators accepting nullable for structs? I.e. have both public static bool operator <(MyStruct left, MyStruct right) => ... AND public static bool operator <(MyStruct? left, MyStruct? right) =>  ..

Comment: @JarekKardas: I think you misunderstood me. When you provide a user-defined `<` on your struct `S`, you get a lifted one provided by the compiler for free, but *only* lifted to `S?`  You don't get `Task<bool> operator <(Task<S> x, Task<S> y)`, or `IEnumerable<bool> operator < (IEnumerable<S>, IEnumerable<S>)` or `MyFavouriteMonad<bool> operator < (MyFavouriteMonad<S>, MyFavouriteMonad<S>)`.  Nullable is special in C#.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you can use reflector why don't you compile this code:

```
int? value = 10;
Console.WriteLine(value == 10);
```

and then open it in reflector? You'll see this (make sure to select 'None' as .net version to decompile to):

```
int? value;
int? CS$0$0000;
&value = new int?(10);
CS$0$0000 = value;
Console.WriteLine((&CS$0$0000.GetValueOrDefault() != 10) ? 0 : &CS$0$0000.HasValue);
```

So basically the compiler does the heavy lifting for you. It understands what '==' operation means when used with nullables and compiles the necessary checks accordingly.

Comment: because I don't have Reflector...I was getting the reflected code from a different SO answer, as I mentioned at the beginning of my question.

Comment: This shows how the compiler works, but not how the language works.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler [converts `Nullable<T>` to `T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131345.aspx) and *then* performs the comparison.

Comment: Judging from @zespri's answer, that appears to be the case. +1

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable<T>` has [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346.aspx):

```
public static implicit operator T?(T value)
{
  return new T?(value);
}
```

It looks like there is an implicit conversion from it `10` to `Nullable<int> 10`

To make == / != work for you. You can add

```
public static bool operator ==(MyNullable<T> left, MyNullable<T> right) {}
// together with:
public static implicit operator MyNullable<T>(T value) {}
```

should give you support for `myNullable == 10` operation

Comment: Yes, but as I said in my question, the `==` operator is not defined for `Nullable<T>`, so if you have two `Nullable<T>`s, you shouldn't be able to do `==`.

Comment: Right. I included `operator ==` just to show how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is language dependent. C# and Visual Basic emit different code when dealing with operators on nullable value types. To udnerstand it you need to look at the actual IL code.

Comment: You're right, but I think in this case, the issue is that the compiler is doing some special stuff for `Nullable<T>` that it's not doing for my code.