# Nullable types and assignment operator

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, nullable, assignment-operator

I always thought that the nullable types of the .NET framework where nothing but a nice construct that the framework gave us, but wasn't anything new added to the language itself.

That is, until today, for purposes of a demonstration, I tried to create my own Nullable struct.

I get everything I need, except the capability of doing this:

```
var myInt = new Nullable<int>(1);
myInt = 1;
```

The problem is the second statement, as I cannot, by any means, overload the assignment operator.

My question is: Is this a special case in the language where the assignment operator has an overload? If not, how would you approach making that previous example work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The assignment is question is handled using an implicit operator declared as:

[`public static implicit operator Nullable<T> (T value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346.aspx)

This is handled without any language-specific features.

The main change to the langauge for nullable support is the ability to write this as:

```
 int? myInt = 1;
```

You could implement this in your type via:

```
public static implicit operator Nullable<T> (T value)
{
    return new Nullable<T>(value);
}
```

That being sad, there is a lot of features related to `Nullable<T>` the C# language and CLR does that [can't be duplicated in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9013171/65358).

Comment: Good answer. Also, the CLR has support for boxing nullable with a value of null to a null reference.

Answer (score 5):

Ditto on the other answers, but note that `Nullable<T>` does do some [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012934/why-does-the-operator-work-for-nullablet-when-is-not-defined) as well.

Quoting from that answer by Lippert

> C# automatically lifts operators to nullable. There's no way to say
>   "automatically lift operators to MyNullable". You can get pretty close
>   by writing your own user-defined operators though.
>
> C# has special rules for null literals -- you can assign them to
>   nullable variables, and compare them to nullable values, and the
>   compiler generates special code for them.
>
> The boxing semantics of nullables are deeply weird and baked into the
>   runtime. There is no way to emulate them.
>
> Nullable semantics for the is, as and coalescing operators are baked
>   in to the language.
>
> Nullables do not satisfy the struct constraint. There is no way to
>   emulate that.
>
> And so on.

Answer (score 3):

Not the assignment operator is overloaded, but the class `Nullable<T>` specifies an implicit conversion operator which is able to convert `T` into `Nullable<T>`.

You can easily add this functionality to your class:

```
class MyInteger {
  private int value;

  public MyInteger(int value) { this.value = value; }

  public static implicit operator MyInteger(int value) {
    return new MyInteger(value);
  }
}
```

And then use the operator in the same way:

```
MyInteger obj = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this page [Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Note that the assignment operator itself (=) cannot be overloaded.

You can define an  [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)