# Check two null and eqauilty In LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am not strong in LinQ
So I try to check if two property is not null and one of them is equal variable number

so

```
public static string FilldrpRequestExecutionUnitsEmployee(int unitID)
{
    List<ApplicationStep> myAppList = 
        new ApplicationStepLogic(ApplicationType.Web)
        .GetAll()
        .Where(x => x.UnitId ==(int?) unitID && (x.UnitId && x.variable != null));
    return "";
}
```

please help 
I am linq beginner

Comment: (x.UnitId != null && x.variable != null), but you can just remove it as you're comparing to unitID which is not null

Comment: Sorry can't understand you

Comment: Assuming that `x.UnitId` is a `int?` then you cannot just "and" it to another `bool` value.  Did you mean to use `x.UnitId.HasValue()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
....
.Where(x => x.UnitId == (int?)unitID && x.variable != null)
.ToList();
```

You don't need the additional null check on the `UnitId` nullable if you already compare it with the casted `unitID`-int. [`Nullable<T>.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6(v=vs.110).aspx) is overridden meaningfully and is safe(no exception if it's `null`). Fyi:[Why does the == operator work for Nullable when == is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012934/why-does-the-operator-work-for-nullablet-when-is-not-defined)

Comment: Error 114 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ESERV.DataMapping.Entity.ApplicationStep>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ESERV.DataMapping.Entity.ApplicationStep>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @saraadly: you need to append `ToList()`. However, it's not clear how you want to convert this list into a `string` that is returned from the method.