# Negation of null for Nullable<bool>

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, logical-operators

I am confused with c# compiler in case of negating the `null` value of `bool?`. Compiler does interpret `!null` as `null`. My expectation is to raise

> CS0266 (Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool')

Sample code:

```
bool? nullableVal = null;

//if (nullableVal)  //OK: CS0266 bool? can't be converted to bool
//    ;
var expectCS0266 = !nullableVal;//No compiler error/warning

//if ((!null) ?? false)//OK: CS8310 Operator '!' cannot be applied to operands of type "<NULL>"
//    ;

if (! nullableVal ?? false)
    ;//this statement isn't reached, because of precedence of ! is higher than ??
    //and !null == null

if (!(nullableVal ?? false))
    ;//this statement is reached, OK
```

Can somebody prove why the compiler is right or vice versa.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9013171/43846) help? - _"Nullable<T> is a very special type and its magical properties are embedded deeply within the C# language and the runtime"_

Comment: @stuartd the answer from canton7 seems to be shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Section 7.3.7 of [the spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> ***Lifted operators*** permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as described in the following:
>
> - For the unary operators
>         `+  ++  -  --  !  ~`
>     a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand and result types are both non-nullable value types. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to the operand and result types. The lifted operator produces a null value if the operand is null. **Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operand, applies the underlying operator, and wraps the result.**

(Emphasis mine)

So:

```
bool? x = null;
bool? y = !x;
```

Follows this rule. We're using the lifted form of the unary `!` operator, which results in `null` if the value it's applied to is `null`.

`!null` isn't allowed, because `null` isn't of type `Nullable<T>`. `!(bool?)null` works, however (although it produces a compiler warning).

`!` indeed has higher precedence than `??`, see Section 7.3.1

Comment: I would mark it __"The lifted operator produces a null value if the operand is null"__ bold. Thank you for quote from spec!