# when C# compare Nullable<T> == null, what happens?

Tags: c#

When C# compares a nullable type to a "null", does the C# compiler insert some code to check if the variable has a value first?

```
int? fk2=null;
OtherNullable<int> fk3=null;

Console.WriteLine(fk2 == null);

Console.WriteLine(fk3 == null);
```

Context, I'm trying to work out what the equality + implicit, and explicit cast should look like to enable the comparison of fk3 and null.

Say that you implemented Nullable as per the code posted here: [How does a Nullable<T> type work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602773/how-does-a-nullablet-type-work-behind-the-scenes) and called it `OtherNullable<T>`

This works fine with little modification, except that val == null will not work at runtime.

Implementation:

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct OtherNullable<T> : IEquatable<OtherNullable<T>> where T : struct {

    private bool hasValue;
    internal T value;

    public OtherNullable(T value)
        : this() {
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }

    public OtherNullable(T? value) {
        this.value = default(T);
        this.hasValue = false;
    }

    public bool HasValue {
        get { return this.hasValue; }
    }

    public T Value {
        get {
            if (!this.HasValue) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No Value");
            }
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    public OtherNullable(bool b) {
        this.value = default(T);
        this.hasValue = false;
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue) {
        if (!this.HasValue) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return this.value;
    }

    public bool Equals(OtherNullable<T> other)
    {
        if (!other.HasValue & !this.HasValue)
            return true;
        else
            return other.hasValue.Equals(hasValue) && other.value.Equals(value);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(OtherNullable<T> left, OtherNullable<T> right) {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(OtherNullable<T> left, OtherNullable<T> right) {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (other.GetType() != typeof(OtherNullable<T>)) return false;
        return Equals((OtherNullable<T>)other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        unchecked {
            return (hasValue.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        if (!this.HasValue) {
            return "";
        }
        return this.value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator OtherNullable<T>(T value) {
        return new OtherNullable<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(OtherNullable<T> value) {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator OtherNullable<T>(Nullable<T> value) {
        if (value.HasValue) {
            return new OtherNullable<T>(value.Value);
        } else {
            return new OtherNullable<T>(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Test Code (will not compile -- it was previously):

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestOtherNullable {
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var a = new OtherNullable<int>();

        a = 1;

        Assert.IsTrue(a.HasValue);
        Assert.IsFalse(a == null);

        var b = new OtherNullable<int>();
        b = null;
        Assert.IsTrue(b == null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equality check of any `Nullable<T>` to `null` is *equivalent* to `!nullable.HasValue`. There are no other semantics for it that would make sense. I 'm not sure what the deal with `OtherNullable<T>` is, since that's not a standard type.

Comment: I added a link to some code that was posted to SO.  It's supposed to be what reflector decompiles the Nullable struct to.  See new info in body of question.

Comment: @sgtz: If the question is why `fk3 == null` does not work, the answer is because you have not [overridden the equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx.aspx). I still do not understand why you would want to implement `OtherNullable` yourself.

Comment: see response from Bob2Chiv.  The compiler does insert code.  I did override the equality operator.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Had another go at implementing equality operators... and... it worked (see updated question code).  If C# does implement the if tests listed above, I wonder if it does this for speed?  Interesting.  Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: "When C# compares a nullable type to a "null", does the C# compiler
> insert some code to check if the variable has a value first?"

A: The compiler does not insert code in this instance. In this case, the Equals operator is overridden like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (!this.HasValue)
    {
        return (other == null);
    }
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this.value.Equals(other);
}
```

Which does take care of comparing it to null.

The compiler **does** help you in the following ways:

```
// this
int? x = null;
// Transformed to this
int? x = new Nullable<int>()

// this
if (x == null) return;
// Transformed to this
if (!x.HasValue) return;

// this
if (x == 2) return;
// Transformed to this
if (x.GetValueOrDefault() == 2 && x.HasValue) return;
```

All of this information is in the question that you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602773/how-does-a-nullablet-type-work-behind-the-scenes).

Thanks to @barrylloyd and @ChaosPandion

Comment: +1: I must have missed **if (!x.HasValue) return;** and **if (x.GetValueOrDefault() == 2 && x.HasValue) return;**.  I thought that you might have been able to be smart with the cast and equality overloads.  I'll leave this question open a little bit longer though just in case someone knows a way.  ty