# Reference types vs Nullable types ToString()

Tags: c#, null, nullable, value-type, reference-type

Could someone please be kind enough to explain why calling `ToString()` on an empty reference type causes an exception (which in my mind makes perfect sense, you cant invoke a method on nothing!) but calling `ToString()` on an empty `Nullable(Of T)` returns `String.Empty`? This was quite a surprise to me as I assumed the behaviour would be consistent across types.

```
Nullable<Guid> value = null;
Stock stock = null;
string result = value.ToString(); //Returns empty string
string result1 = stock.ToString(); //Causes a NullReferenceException
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is actually a `struct` that has some compiler support and implementation support to behave like a `null` without actually being `null`.

What you are seeing is the collision between the implementation allowing you to treat it naturally as a `null` as you would any other reference type, but allowing the method call to happen because the `Nullable<T>` isn't actually null, the value inside it is null.

*Visually* it looks like it shouldn't work, this is simply because you cannot *see* what is done in the background for you.

Other such visual trickery can be seen when you call an extension method on a null reference type... the call works (against visual expectation) because under the hood it is resolved into a static method call passing your null instance as a parameter.

[How does a Nullable<T> type work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602773/how-does-a-nullablet-type-work-behind-the-scenes)

Comment: Depends on your visual expectations. Some would say that it's the fact that calling an non-virtual method that doesn't reference any fields or virtual methods *does* throw an exception that's against expectation, since there's no real reason for it except that C# forces it (.NET however doesn't force this).

Comment: @JonHanna Not really, I would expect that to fail based on the fact it *looks* like a instance-method call, regardless of the fact it can be redefined as a static without any issue. But I see your point that expectation will be tainted based on experience. In the OPs case I think it stands though.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't expect it to fail, because I wouldn't expect `class A{public void DoNothing(){}};/*...*/(A(null)).DoNothing();` to fail. There's no reason for it to fail, but C# made an extra effort to make it fail that other languages don't.
Since I wouldn't expect it to fail as a non-extension method, I wouldn't expect it to fail as an extension method either, until I learn about C# having a special case of throwing on safe calls to methods of null objects.

Comment: @JonHanna You mean unlearn from other languages? To me it seems natural that trying to call an instance member on a null item regardless of its implementation will cause issues. I'm in the boat where my main language experience comes from C#, and based on language used by the OP in the question I still think my terminology stands. I'd also initially think they didn't make *extra* effort to make it fail, they just didn't make extra effort to make it work based on what `DoSomething` actually does.

Comment: One has to unlearn in all cases, and C#'s special-casing of this is one of those things (and isn't explicitly stated anywhere official that I've seen, though I could have just missed it). It doesn't help that there's no logical reason for it, it's "just because, that's why".

Comment: @JonHanna Lots of design decisions that people don't explain fall under the banner of "just because, that's why", just that this one is more obvious when you boil it down to what you are trying to do and what the compiler says in response. The confusion comes in when the code itself *looks* consistent yet is not consistent in behaviour - the OPs original source of confusion, expectations based on what it looks like will happen, but the implementation / compiler under the covers does something else. Your point falls into this category too.

Comment: It's hardly obvious that I run code that doesn't dereference anything and it throws a `NullReferenceException`. That's like eating too much and consequently breaking a finger.
And they did make an extra effort to fail, they call non-virtual methods with `callvirt` rather than `call` precisely to make it fail (analogous to the metaphor, they by-passed my stomach through my finger-bone, just so it would break if I ate too much).

Comment: @JonHanna Fair enough, but I feel that extra effort is warranted as it is entirely based on the implementation as to whether the call succeeds or not. And when this is considered as the regular behaviour on instance members, what look like the same type of calls in C# code (extension methods or in the OPs case calling a method on what appears to be null) then the change in behaviour from what *appears* to be happening is the source of confusion because you cannot take appearance alone. I wouldn't like method calls to start working on nulls *just because* I don't reference any instance members.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14847/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-adam-houldsworth)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth what compiler support?  Looking at the code behind Nullable, it appears to be easily implemented anywhere?

Comment: @MAfifi Null assignment doesn't come from the implementation (`Nullable<bool> b = null;`). Other than that I'm not really sure, all I know is the compiler chips in to allow it to do what it does.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I consider the fact that there's no way to specify that an instance method should be legal on null instances to be a deficiency in .net language design; if .net is going to have the default value of `String` behave like an empty string in some contexts (probably trying to improve COM interoperation), it should be consistent.  Of course, that might require that `Nullable<T>` lose the silly `struct` constraint, but that would be a good thing anyway.

Comment: @supercat Yeah I see what you're saying. But for it to be safe the compiler would have to guard against member variable access, so it may as well be static. That said, static method calls on instances (null or otherwise) could be a good halfway house.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Attempting to access a member variable of a null reference will trigger a null-reference exception regardless of whether the compiler allows calls to non-virtual instance members of null references.  The difference would be that something like `String.Length` could check `if (this==null) return 0;` without throwing a null reference exception (thus allowing `String` to behave consistently like a value type which defaults to an empty string).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: On a related note, I'd probably have `Object.Equals` be a non-virtual wrapper around a virtual `Equals` function which would check for reference equality or nullity before calling the virtual method; such a method should be short enough to be inlined; the improvement in the reference-equals case should likely offset the cost of doing the extra testing before invoking the virtual method.

Answer (score 6):

Nullable is a value type and the assignment to `null` causes it to be initialized with `Value=null` and `HasValue=false`.

Further, Nullable.ToString() is implement as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (!this.HasValue)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return this.value.ToString();
}
```

So what you are seeing is expected.

Comment: I think the question is more "how is that ToString called at all, since value is null?".

Comment: Value doesn't get initialized to null, it gets initialized to default(T). Value is a value type, it can't be null. Actually Value is a property so it doesn't get initialized to anything, but its backing field gets initialized to default(T), although you will never see that value because the property will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit tricky with nullable types. When you set it to `null` it is actualy not `null` cause it is not reference type (it is value type). When you initialize such variable with `null` it creates new sctructure instance where `HasValue` property is `false` and it's `Value` is `null`, so when you call `ToString` method it works well on structure instance.

Comment: It is actually null. The concept of null and nothingness predates the concept of references in computing. That we may represent this concept by a reference that doesn't refer, it's not the only possible way. Nullable value-types are another.

Comment: @JonHanna: You're half right.  True, the concept of nullity in general predates the concept of references.  But user854301 here is saying that when you set a nullable type **in C#** to `null` it is not actually `null` -- which is 100% correct.  The word `null` (especially when written in a code font) has a specific meaning in the context of C# which is separate from (although related to) the concept of nullity in general.  It's like saying that `42.0` is an integer -- it certainly *is*, in a general existential way, but from a language point of view it's a `double` instead.

Comment: @DanielPryden if we do `double? d = null;` we've assigned null to `d`. If we test `double == null` then we get `true`. As far as the C# meaning of `null` goes, `d` is `null`. It's not however a *null reference* because while it's null, it's not a reference.

Comment: Equals method is override for nullable types. All of this stuff were design to support communication with db (point of view) not to simply add 'another type'.

Comment: @user854301 DB work is far from their only use (DBs have nullable for a reason, and that reason applies elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

The exception raised by calling `default(object).ToString()` is called `NullReferenceException` for a reason, it's calling a method on a null reference. `default(int?)` on the other hand, is not a null reference, because it's not a reference; it is a value type with a value that is *equivalent* to null.

The big practical point, is that if this was done, then the following would fail:

```
default(int?).HasValue // should return false, or throw an exception?
```

It would also screw-up the way we have some ability to mix nullables and non-nullables:

```
((int?)null).Equals(1) // should return false, or throw an exception?
```

And the following becomes completely useless:

```
default(int?).GetValueOrDefault(-1);
```

We could get rid of `HasValue` and force comparison with null, but then what if the equality override of the value-type that is made nullable can return true when compared to null in some cases. That may not be a great idea, but it can be done and the language has to cope.

Let's think back to why nullable types are introduced. The possibility that a reference type can be null, is inherent in the concept of reference types unless effort is taken to enforce non-nullability: Reference types are types that refer to something, and that implies the possibility of one not referring to anything, which we call *null*.

While a nuisance in many cases, we can make use of this in a variety of cases, such as representing "unknown value", "no valid value" and so on (we can use it for what *null* means in databases, for example).

At this point, we've given *null* a meaning in a given context, beyond the simple fact that a given reference doesn't refer to any object.

Since this is useful, we could therefore want to set an `int` or `DateTime` to null, but we can't because they aren't types that refer to something else, and hence can't be in a state of not referring to anything any more than I as a mammal can lose my feathers.

The nullable types introduced with 2.0 give us a form of value types that can have the semantic *null*, through a different mechanism than that of reference types. Most of this you could code yourself if it didn't exist, but special boxing and promotion rules allow for more sensible boxing and operator use.

Okay. Now let's consider why `NullReferenceExceptions` happen in the first place. Two are inevitable, and one was a design decision in C# (and doesn't apply to all of .NET).

1. You try to call a virtual method or property, or access a field on a null reference. This has to fail, because there's no way to look up what override should be called, and no such field.
2. You call a non-virtual method or property on a null reference which in turn calls a virtual method or property, or accesses a field. This is obviously a variant on point one, but the design decision we're coming to next has the advantage of guaranteeing this fails at the start, rather than part-way through (which could be confusing and have long-term side-effects).
3. You call a non-virtual method or property on a null reference which does not call a virtual method or property, or access a field. There's no inherent reason why this should not be allowed, and some languages allow it, but in C# they decided to use `callvirt` rather than `call` to force a `NullReferenceException` for the sake of consistency (can't say I agree, but there you go).

None of these cases apply in any way to a nullable value type. It is impossible to put a nullable value type into a condition in which there is no way to know which field or method override to access. The whole concept of `NullReferenceException` just doesn't make sense here.

In all, not throwing a `NullReferenceException` **is** consistent with the other types - types through it if and only if a null reference is used.

Note that there is a case where calling on a null nullable-type throws, it does so with `GetType()`, because `GetType()` is not virtual, and when called on a value-type there is always an implied boxing. This is true of other value types so:

```
(1).GetType()
```

is treated as:

```
((object)1).GetType()
```

But in the case of nullable types, boxing turns those with a false `HasValue` into null, and hence:

```
default(int?).GetType()
```

being treated as:

```
((object)default(int?)).GetType()
```

which results in `GetType()` being called on a null object, and hence throwing.

This incidentally brings us to why not faking `NullReferenceType` was the more sensible design decision - people who need that behaviour can always box. If you want it to through then use `((object)myNullableValue).GetString()` so there's no need for the language to treat it as a special case to force the exception.

**EDIT**

Oh, I forgot to mention the mechanics behind `NullReferenceException`.

The test for `NullReferenceException` is very cheap, because it mostly just ignores the problem, and then catches the exception from the OS if it happens. In other words, there **is no test**.

See [What is the CLR implementation behind raising/generating a null reference exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239410/what-is-the-clr-implementation-behind-raising-generating-a-null-reference-except/11241755#11241755) and note how none of that would work with nullable value types.

Comment: IMHO, .net should have provided a means by which instance methods could be explicitly tagged so as to be callable on null instances; while that would not be expected behavior for mutable reference types, such a design would have allowed immutable reference types like `String` to behave like value types with a meaningful default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you investigate `Nullable<>` definition, there is an override ToString definition. In this function, ToString is overriden to return String.Empty.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Returns the text representation of the value of the current System.Nullable<T>
    //     object.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The text representation of the value of the current System.Nullable<T> object
    //     if the System.Nullable<T>.HasValue property is true, or an empty string ("")
    //     if the System.Nullable<T>.HasValue property is false.
    public override string ToString();
```

On the otherhand, Stock is a custom class, which I assume ToString is not overriden. Thus it returns NullReferenceException since it uses default behaviour.

Comment: This answer misses the key fact that Nullable is a value type.  Calling ToString on any reference type will throw a NullReferenceException, whether the type has a ToString override or not.

Comment: @phoog This answer directly or indirectly does not imply anything related with reference types. Sorry if I can not get the point. I also stated that if it is "a class" and the value is "null"; then the default behaviour returns NullReferenceException.

Comment: Your answer implies that adding a `ToString()` override to the `Stock` class would change the program's behavior, but that's not correct.  The NullReferenceException occurs with `Stock` because `Stock` is a reference type, and it does not occur with `Nullable<Guid>` because `Nullable<>` is a value type.  The presence or absence of a `ToString()` override has no bearing on whether a NullReferenceException is thrown.  In other words, the problem with the answer is precisely that it does not mention the issue of value types vs. reference types.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN Remarks

> [Guid.ToSTring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) method Returns a string representation of the
>   value of this Guid instance, according to the provided format
>   specifier.

As per MSDN Remarks on [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

> A type is said to be nullable if it can be assigned a value or can be
>   assigned null, which means the type has no value whatsoever.
>   Consequently, a nullable type can express a value, or that no value
>   exists. For example, a reference type such as String is nullable,
>   whereas a value type such as Int32 is not. A value type cannot be
>   nullable because it has enough capacity to express only the values
>   appropriate for that type; it does not have the additional capacity
>   required to express a value of null.

Comment: Please read my full answer it was incomplete when you read it